# no redirecciona completamente

Tags: express

Tengo un enlace, quiero redirigir a listaEvaluacionesInvestigacion.

```
a(id='add-user', href="/evaluacion/listaEvaluacionesInvestigacion", 
class='btn btn-primary') agregar los usuarios marcados
```

and the router is

```
router.get('/listaEvaluacionesInvestigacion', function (req, res) { console.log('ENTRA A LA FUNCION'); res.render('./evaluacion/listaEvaluaciones',{}); });
```

shows the message of console.log(), what it does is change the url but it does not show the content of listaEvaluaciones

PERO se muestra cuando actualizo la página (porque está actualizada ya que cambió la url)

¿Cómo lo soluciono? Quiero mostrar el contenido de la página sin refrescar *

Comment: ¿Que es exprimir? ese tag no tiene descripcion.

Comment: @eyllanesc nose como puse exprimir, quise poner express